# JPA repository : issue with saving an entity in a big table - timeout error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, repository

I am using jpa repository.
I want to save an entity in a Mysql table which contains 100000 records.

When I do

```
FraisProvision fraisProv = new FraisProvision();
...
fraisProvisionRepository.save(fraisProv);
```

I am getting this error `

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction

It worked well when the mysql table wasn't that big.
If I insert a record in this table via MysqlWorkbench, the record is inserted instantly.
I don't understand why using jpa repository takes so long to insert the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding ?autoReconnect=true to your URI. For example:
mysql://db_user:db_user@localhost/mydb?autoReconnect=true
It worked for me.